# How to use environment variable in index.html for Angular 6

Tags: angular6, account-kit

I am using angular6, in my project I am using Facebook Account Toolkit for mobile verification purpose.

I need to initialise Account toolkit in index.html file using following code.

```
  AccountKit.init({
   appId:"XX",
   state:"xx",
   version:"v1.2",
   fbAppEventsEnabled:true,
   debug:true
 });
```

The problem is, values for **appId** and **state** change depending on environment (development/test/production).

How can I use environment variables in `index.html` file.

Please let me know if anyone has a solution for angular 6.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You should create copy of index.html and name it `index.someenv.html`.
Then in your angular.json in environment configuration setup file replacement:

```
"fileReplacements": [
    {
        "replace": "src/index.html",
        "with": "src/index.someenv.html"
    }
]
```

The angular cli will replace these files when you run your build

**UPD: For Angular 8+ use this:**

Add the following to your angular.json:

```
"production": {
  "index": {
    "input": "src/index.someenv.html",
    "output": "index.html"
  },
},
```

Comment: I am doing this but for some reason it still copies over the original index.html file. I am using the following command to build the angular app: `ng build --prod -c production --output-path dist`. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't replace the index.html file with index.prod.html ?

Comment: @DejanBogatinovski can you show your configuration for production? (in angular.json)

Comment: Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jysqkn9pf5z39y4/Screenshot_1.png?dl=1

Comment: I am facing the same issue with replacing index ("index.html" not getting replaced with "index.prod.html"). However, this solution is working for
 {"replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
 "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts" }.

Comment: @JosephHorsch only the content of index.html will be replaced, not the filename.

Comment: @DejanBogatinovski As of angular 8, you can't replace index files via `"fileReplacements"`. You have to specify your own index file via `"index"` property. 
Eg.: `"index":"src/index.someenv.html"`.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62104390/494560) for Angular 8 and above

Answer (score 50):

This answer supersedes [Artyom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52371747/494560) for Angular 8 and above. Add the following to your `angular.json`:

```
"production": {
  "index": {
    "input": "src/index.someenv.html",
    "output": "index.html"
  },
},
```

Comment: This would also be great to do in a CI build. have index.tokens.html contain __MY_PLACEHOLDER__. index.html contains the default for local development, and in your pipeline just before your prod build do a replacement of __MY_PLACEHOLDER__ with a pipeline variable. This allows values like environment URLs to be stored in the pipeline and a change to them would be to simply re-run the pipeline for a given commit to generate the file with the new URL instead of needing a code change to have to be promoted through various environments.

Answer (score 6):

An example here for document.write(environment.variable) :
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4451#issuecomment-285026543

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">// ProductionAnalyticsCodeHere</script>');
} else if (environment.staging) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">// StagingAnalyticsCodeHere</script>');
}
```

Comment: This one is kinda dangerous, because `document.write` will replace *whole* HTML document if invoked after page is being loaded.

Answer (score 6):

for me above answers did not work on Angular 10, so I created different folder for staging, production etc and placed the index.html which was used by CLI as per the build environment

```
{
  "projects": {
    "yourApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "index": "src/index.html",
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "index": "src/production/index.html",
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I confirm, This solution worked for me, on angular 13

Comment: OK, that's weird.  I was set to also confirm that jscroll's solution didn't work in Ang 13/14: (`Index html generation failed \r\n ENDENT: no such file or directory, open C:\blah\blah\ClientApp\src\index.test.html`), but after I successfully followed this solution and then tried it again (just to test/report whether it was the name of the index file or whether it needed to be in its own folder), jscroll's solution started working.  Go figure.

Comment: This worked for the default(index.html), but for the dev(index.dev.html), I also had to do ```mv dist/index.dev.html dist/index.html```

Answer (score 5):

In main.ts file you can use `document.write(environment.variable)` and it will write what you want in index.html

(I use it to make the Google Analytics script take a dynamic Tracking ID wether it's in development or production mode, and it works well in Angular6)

Comment: Hi, would you have a small example to show how you managed to update your Analytics script Tracking ID in your index.html file? Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Avoid direct access to the document object by injecting DOCUMENT to your AppComponent.

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...
  public constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: any
  ) {
```

Add the  tag in ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.setYourScriptTag();
}
```

private function to set it

```
  private setYourScriptTag() {
    const s = this.doc.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.innerHTML = `AccountKit.init({
   appId: "${environment.appId}",
   state: "${environment.state}",
   version:"v1.2",
   fbAppEventsEnabled:true,
   debug:true
 });`;
    const head = this.doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(s);
  }
```

This answer is from edodusi

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4451#issuecomment-384992203

Answer (score 2):

##### Angular 16: File replacement approach

```json
"production": {
       "index": "src/index.html",
},
"development": {
       "index": "src/index.development.html",
}
```

Using two different HTML file

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it all in main.ts

```
const env = environment;

 AccountKit.init({
   appId:env.appId,  // this lane
   state:env.state,  // this lane
   version:"v1.2",
   fbAppEventsEnabled:true,
   debug:true
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue with loading google charts js and needing to pass the correct api from the environment variables. Moving the initialize call to main.ts worked for me. Of course timing issues are always a concern when loading/initializing scripts so let us know if it works in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I added this in main.ts:

```
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML
document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.replace("Replace me!", environment.variable)
```

Note that the old value will still exist in index.html for some time while the page is initially loading. (For example, use this to replace the page title and you'll see the old value displayed before the replace happens.)

Comment: FWIW: There is an alternate for setting the title that does not suffer from above @ZX9 mentioned latency, per the Angular docs - https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title.

Answer (score -5):

import your environment file into .ts file.

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

Create required fields in your class, assign values from **environment** to these variables in the constructor, use usual binding in the .html file.

.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public production = true;
  constructor() {
    this.production = environment.production;
  }
}
```

.html

```
<span>{{production}}</span>
```

Comment: thanks, Igor Litvinovich, but I want to use that env variable in index.html , not in .ts file to that particular html file, i am using angular6. and import not working in index.html file.