# Implement page tracking using GTM in Angular 6 Index.html page

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular6, google-tag-manager

I need to track my page views using GTM code in Angular 6 application. 
Pasted below line of code in Index.html page and my value for Prod_GTM_ID will change based on different environments.

To get dynamic values, as mentioned(3rd answer) in URL [How to use environment variable in index.html for Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050519/how-to-use-environment-variable-in-index-html-for-angular-6), I followed the steps but using {{Prod_GTM_ID}} shows error 'Property assignment expected.(undefined)'

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer',{{Prod_GTM_ID}});</script>
```

How to import environment variables inside index.html page.
Is there any simplest approach to achieve the same.