# How to change variable value in index.html based on the environment in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

How can i change config.apiKey value based on the angular environments like Development & Production.

```
For Production config.appKey = 'AB-AAB-AAB-MPR';

For Development config.appKey = 'AC-DDR-SST-DKR';

Please find the code for reference.

`<script charset='UTF-8'>
    window['adrum-start-time'] = new Date().getTime();
    (function(config){
        config.appKey = 'AC-DDR-SST-DKR';
    })(window['adrum-config'] || (window['adrum-config'] = {}));
  </script>
`

Thanks
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reading environment file in index.html will be difficult. I am not saying it is not possible there may be a workaround for that. But I recommend you to do this in app.component.ts file on

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScript();
}

private loadScript() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.innerHTML = 'window["adrum-start-time"] = new Date().getTime(); (function(config){ config.appKey = ' + environment.key + '; })(window["adrum-config"] || (window["adrum-config"] = {}));';
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (head !== null && head !== undefined) {
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use your angular.json to replace your `index.html` file.
just create a copy of the `index.html` and name it to `index.env.html`
and then in your `angular.json`  you can use  `fileReplacements` in your specific env like the following

```
"fileReplacements": [
    {
        "replace": "src/index.html",
        "with": "src/index.env.html"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `isDevMode()`

or else use this way

```
└──myProject/src/environments/
                   └──environment.ts
                   └──environment.prod.ts
                   └──environment.stage.ts
```

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://my-api-url'
};
```

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'http://my-prod-url'
};
```

Read more on [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments)

Answer (score 0):

you can add those key in `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` file so you need to write the development api key in `environment.ts` and production key in `environment.prod.ts` so if you are creating a build by using a this command `ng build --prod` it will take the api key from `environment.prod.ts` file. here is the example

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  appKey: 'AB-AAB-AAB-MPR';
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  appKey: 'AC-DDR-SST-DKR';
};
```

**service**

```
// here we are importing our environment like this 
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

getData() {
   console.log(environment.apiKey);
// here you will get the apiKey based on your environment if it is dev environment then it take the "apiKey" from environment.ts and if it is production env then it will take the "apiKey" from the environment.prod.ts
// api call or other business logic 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution here: [How to use environment variable in index.html for Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050519/how-to-use-environment-variable-in-index-html-for-angular-6)

TL,DR: use files for each enviroment and config it in angular.json

Answer (score 0):

I created different folder for prod, staging etc environment and instead of using variable, I placed three different index.html as per the environment, I answered the same here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67091452/1843984

Answer (score -1):

you can simply either use env files to manage your different environments or else you can also use this i have use in my react app as below
in your package.json use

```
 "start": "react-scripts start",
        "start:staging": "REACT_APP_BUILD_TYPE=staging  npm start",
        "start:prod": "REACT_APP_BUILD_TYPE=production  npm start",
        "build": "REACT_APP_BUILD_TYPE=production react-scripts build",
        "build:staging": "REACT_APP_BUILD_TYPE=staging react-scripts build",
},
```

and the file you have written above can be use as

```
"REACT_APP_BUILD_TYPE=staging ? config.appKey = 'AB-AAB-AAB-MPR' : config.appKey = 'AC-DDR-SST-DKR';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'http://my-api-url',
  appKey: 'AC-DDR-SST-DKR'
};
```

check the angular.json file for fileReplacements config
here it is: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftda85)

Comment: but how i will pass that appKey value to index.html as index.html runs out of angular context

Comment: I have updated it in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftda85
please look at 
app.component.html,
app.component.ts